# Use of Interface and Abstract Class for Specific to my application?

Tags: asp.net, oop

I am asp.net programmer and i have two application one is like eCommerce application like eBay site and other is management like say store management system say like bigbazzar or any book store etc .

Now i wanted to implement interface and abstract class in my projects.i have read about the abstract class and interface and know hoe to use therotically.but am looking for the real world or practical example of both which is relevant to my applications.(i.e. for eCommerce & store management)
I have search a lot for sample web eCommerce and management where interfaces and abstract classes are beautifully used.
Can any body help me how to use interface and abstract class used in my eCommerce & store management application.

It is good if you can share any relevant (i.e. ecomm and store management) application or project where abstract class and interface used ,so i can easily correlate with my project due to relevancey.

Comment: This question seems too open-ended. Abstraction isn't something that is specific to any type of project but instead, relates to the over all design of the object model.

Comment: The problem with this question is the answer you are requesting won't help you. You may know the how, you don't appear to have got the why though. If you had got the why, potential candidates in any application would be leaping out at you. It's not a case of when you should use abstraction, it's when you should stop...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely broad and as @doogle mentioned in the comment, Abstract classes and interfaces aren't necessarily tied to a specific type of project, but are based on your design.

Without knowing the design of your eCommerce or store management applications, it is impossible to give you any specific help, but in reading one of your earlier questions, it looks like you might be trying to understand how abstract classes and interfaces might be able to help you, so here is a basic example of something that might point you in the right direction.

In a hypothetical store you have thousands of different products and you want to track them in your application.  There are obviously things common to all products, like manufacturer, price, department, quantity, but also pieces of information that might only be applicable to specific products (clothing would have a size, but a DVD wouldn't).

A solution might be to create a `Product` interface that would be common to all Products but allow each class to implement the interface and add their own Properties.  Now you can guarantee that any product class would have, at minimum, these common members.

Here's a hypothetical Product interface:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
    decimal StoreCost { get; set; }
    int QuantityOnHand { get; set; }

    string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    decimal CalculateProfit();
}
```

Then you could create an abstract class that implements `IProduct`.  Here's a clothing product that implements `IProduct` but also adds a `Size` field

```
public abstract class ClothingProduct : IProduct
{
    public string Size { get; set; }

    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal StoreCost { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOnHand { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    // by marking CalculateProfits abstract, you can let every class that inherits
    //  from ClothingProduct decide how to calculate the profit based on the selling
    //  costs of that product
    public abstract decimal CalculateProfit(); 
}
```

Now that you have a `ClothingProduct` class, you could then go and create classes for some of the items in the store.  Here's a Shoes and Shirt class:

```
public class Shirt : ClothingProduct
{
    public override CalculateProfit()
    {
        return this.SellingPrice - this.StoreCost - this.CalculateSellingCosts();
    }

    private decimal CaclulateSellingCosts()
    {
        // some code that would let you calculate the selling costs and
        //  overhead costs associated with this specific product
    }
}

public class Shoes : ClothingProduct
{
    private const decimal commissionRate = 0.05;

    public override CalculateProfit()
    {
        return this.SellingPrice - this.StoreCost - this.CalculateSellingCosts() - this.CalculateCommission();
    }

    private decimal CaclulateSellingCosts()
    {
        // some code that would let you calculate the selling costs and
        //  overhead costs associated with this specific product
    }

    private decimal CalculateCommission()
    {
        return this.SellingPrice * commissionRate;
    }
}
```

In the end, both `Shoes` and `Shirt` are `IProducts` because they inherit from `ClothingProduct` which in turn implements `IProduct`.

Could you create other classes or abstract classes for other products throughout the store, but as long as the implement `IProduct`, you can guarantee that they would have all of the Properties that are part of `IProduct`.

Where this helps is you could even create a collection of your interface types and add all products to it since the all implement `IProduct`

```
// a hypothetical method that grabs everything  (maybe from a database)
List<IProduct> products = GetAllProducts(); 

// this query would give you the total number of items in your inventory
var totalItems = products.Select(quant => quant.QuantityOnHand).Sum();

// and this would calculate the total value of the products based on the store's cost
var totalCost =  products.Select(quant => quant.StoreCost).Sum();
```

The 2 queries are just contrived examples as it would just as easy to do this in the database (if that is where everythign is store), but I just did it to give you an example of how tying all related items back to a single interface can help